# Unable to set Value on a Range of cells

Tags: google-sheets-api

So I've been looking around for something but everything I've used doesn't work.

What i'm looking to do is just clear a range of cells and set them to ☐ from ☑

EG. select the range then just set them all to ☐.

Now as i said I've used the default codes but no matter what script i use it does nothing :S

Anyone able to help?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: These are the two ive tried: 

function SetRange() {
  function SetRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Mythic Tracker');
  sheet.getRange('o16:o18'); setValue('☐');  }
}
  

function reset() {
 function reset() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange("o16");
 cell.setValue("☐");
}}


what im expecting to happen is the selected range to change to the empty box, but nothing happens

Comment: Pleae edit your answer instead of adding comments here. Format your code, so that it's readable.